# SQL Where Not Exists - Mulitple WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to SQL. I am trying to write a script to get the last occurrence (date) of a particular transaction type (disposition) of a particular item number.

The table looks like below

```
ID    ITEMNO    TRANS_DATE  TRANS_TYPE
1     XYZ           12/4/2015   DISPOSITION
2     ABC           12/6/2015   NEW ITEM
3     XYZ           12/14/2015  DISPOSITION
```

I want the result of the script of ITEMNO 'XYZ' to be Disposition 12/14/2015.

```
    select ITEMNO, TRANS_DATE, TRANS_TYPE from TRANSLOG t
    where not exists(select tt.Id 
        from TRANSLOG tt
        where tt.TRANS_TYPE=t.TRANS_TYPE and
            tt.Id>t.Id
    )
    AND
    ITEMNO ='XYZ'
    AND
    TRANS_TYPE = 'DISPOSITION'

order by t.TRANS_TYPE
```

The above script returns no results.

Comment: script returns results here.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f1eaa/1

Comment: Well drafted question for a new post. Keep it up! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to get a list of `(ItemNo, 'DISPOSITION', MAX(Trans_Date))`, then join it to the full table. Only `DISPOSITION` items with the most recent transaction date will make it to the results:

```
SELECT
  TransLog.ItemNo,
  TransLog.Trans_Date,
  TransLog.Trans_Type
FROM TransLog
JOIN (
  SELECT ItemNo, Trans_Type, MAX(Trans_Date) AS MostRecent
  FROM TransLog
  WHERE ItemNo = 'XYZ' AND Trans_Type = 'DISPOSITION'
  GROUP BY ItemNo, Trans_Type
) MaxDates ON
  TransLog.ItemNo = MaxDates.ItemNo AND
  TransLog.Trans_Type = MaxDates.Trans_Type AND
  TransLog.Trans_Date = MaxDates.MostRecent
WHERE TransLog.Trans_Type = 'DISPOSITION'
ORDER BY TransLog.Trans_Type
```

If you want the results to include the most recent `DISPOSITION` records for *all* items, just remove the `ItemNo = 'XYZ'` from inner query's `WHERE` clause.

There's a working SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f1eaa/3) - thanks @JamieD77 for setting it up :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One thing to note: when using the ItemNo, the results were blank. I changed it and used the Itemno_ID and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If we stick to your statement,

> I am trying to write a script to get the last occurrence (date) of a
>   particular transaction type (disposition) of a particular item number.

That means a **single item number**. So can't you do this?

```
SELECT ITEMNO, MAX(TRANS_DATE), TRANS_TYPE
FROM TRANSLOG
WHERE ITEMNO = 'XYZ' AND TRANS_TYPE = 'DISPOSITION';
```

[SQL Fiddle thanks to @JamieD77 again =)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f1eaa/5)

```
ITEMNO  MAX(TRANS_DATE)     TRANS_TYPE
XYZ     December, 14 2015 00:00:00  DISPOSITION
```

Comment: I would think that would also work, but I tried it and it gives me an error. At some point, I would like to add additional criteria from another table. i.e. look at the ItemNo table and return the last Disposition date for only those items that C_CODE is null or some other value.

Comment: I see. Error may be due to column names and so on. If you need to connect with another table then yes a join and to check nulls `not exists`.